# On notation of metrics.

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

I tried to read a book on Holomorphic Dynamics, and I found that $dp = \text{something}$ is a metric. In which sense an expression of type "infinitesimal" can be a metric. I only understand metrics as distances. Can you tell me where to read the context of such metrics?

Comment: You use that infinitesimal to do path integration in order to figure out how long a given curve segment is. That's why we can justify calling it a metric. For instance, for the Euclidean metric in the plane, we write $dp=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ where you can recognize the form of the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the book that you mentioned is concerned with [metric tensors on Riemannian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor). They do induce a metric in the usual sense of the word. For instance, the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be obtained by this process.